# Ajax on select input click: Fill options from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want the options in select input to be updated by response from AJAX. The response might differ and the old options should be updated by new ones.

```
<select class="form-control" id="juniorProjects">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

However, I want the method `getProjects()` to be invoked only when clicked on select box and not on any of the options.

```
var juniorProjects = document.getElementById('juniorProjects');
juniorProjects.addEventListener('click', function(){                
    getProjects("junior");
});
```

Right now with this code, whenever I click on any options it triggers select click event and the AJAX response updates the options and by default always selects the first one.

```
function getProjects(type){
    $.ajax({
      url: "SOME_ENDPOINT_TO_GET_PROJECTS",
    }).then(function(data) {                           
        $("#juniorProjects").empty();
        var projectsList = data['result']['recentProjects'];
        for(i=0; i<projectsList.length; i++){
            $("#juniorProjects").append("<option value='" + projectsList[i]['projectId']+ "'>" + projectsList[i]['name'] + "</option>");
        }
    });
}
```

**STRANGE OBSERVATION**: On Macbook Chrome browser - select input click even is not triggered on selecting any option.
On Chromebook chrome browser - select input click even is triggered on selecting any option

Comment: Maybe you want to use focus and not click. And remove the event once it is called.

Comment: Any errors on the Macbook Chrome browser, my friend? :))

Comment: @Tomato32 none at all. Just different behavior on the same browser across different OS

Comment: @kartik: Yeah! That's strange. The same browser, just different OS. Maybe you should try using epascarello's suggestion :))

Comment: you try attaching the eventListener to the parent class document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{ if e.target.id == 'juniorProjects'{ 'LOGIC'} })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the focus event and remove it once you make the call

```
var fetchProjs = function () {
  juniorProjects.removeEventListener('focus', fetchProjs);
  getProjects("junior");
}

juniorProjects.addEventListener('focus', fetchProjs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your event listener after you've added it using removeEventListener.

```js
var juniorProjects = document.getElementById('juniorProjects');
juniorProjects.addEventListener('click', juniorProjectsClicked);

function juniorProjectsClicked(){
    getProjects("junior");
    console.log('in event. This should only print once');
    juniorProjects.removeEventListener('click', juniorProjectsClicked);
}

function getProjects(type){
    // using setTimeout to imitate an ajax request
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#juniorProjects").append("<option>TEST</option>");
    }, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="juniorProjects">
    <option></option>
</select>
```